# How to disable connection pooling when using HttpClient in .NET Framework 4.8 and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to make API calls and I have found that at very high request rates I am getting into weird situations where the connection pool somehow becomes polluted with 1 or 2 bad connections that don't get recycled.  This causes strange behavior.

I want to just turn off connection pooling for `HttpClient` completely in .NET Framework 4.8.  Unfortunately, there is no single simple setting to do this.  It also seems that it is easier to turn this off in .NET Core, but unfortunately we are using .NET Framework.  I have not been able to find any good examples on how to do this.

Any guidance on how to turn off connection pooling would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In SQL using a different connection string uses a different pool... have you tried with a `HttpClient` using different instances per call to remove pooling?

Comment: Are you looking for HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer ?

Comment: @JeremyThompson That doesn't work sadly because it centrally tracks the URLs and pools by URL

Comment: @jeb Well I want to have many concurrent requests, I just don't want to pool my connections

Comment: @Charlieface did you have any luck finding a solution to the problem? I have the same question, since I am communicating with a limited device that can only support one socket at a time.